# Explanation of a vector direction

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

Why does dB have this bearing?

Comment: Biot-Savart's law...The direction from dl × r

Comment: so dB is vertical to dl and vertical to r ?

Comment: @MaryDona perpendicular, you mean?

Comment: Perpendicular to dl and r according to the right-hand thumb rule.

Comment: yes perpendicular, thank you a lot

Comment: Why the angle between dΒy and dΒ is equal to π/2-θ ?